# JMH-based benchmark to measure JVM start-up time

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I'd like to measure JVM start-up time, so is there any approach to do this with JMH?

Currently I'm thinking about the following code, but not sure, whether the measurement is reliable:

```java
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class JvmStartUpBenchmark {

  private final String classpath = "...";
  private final String path = ".../jdk/bin/java";
  private final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
          path,
          "-cp",
          classpath,
          Main.class.getName()
  );

  @Benchmark
  public int jvmStartup() throws Exception {
    return processBuilder.start().waitFor();
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Comment: JMH is made for measuring your methods when those are hot.

Comment: @dan1st right, I'm trying to dodge this with Mode.SingleShotTime